# Create a task that executes another task with arguments

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How to create a task that executes another task with arguments?

taskB will receive arguments from the command line (here it is hard coded to val1 and val2) and I want to pass these arguments to other tasks - for example taskA and taskC, and to define the order in which they will be executed.

This is what I've tried and it isn't working

```
task taskB(){
    def val1 = '1'
    def val2 = 'abc'

    dependsOn "taskA -PparamA=$val1 -PparamB=$val2",
              "taskC -PparamA=$val1 -PparamB=$val2"

    taskC.mustRunAfter taskA
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
task taskA() << {
    //properties are printed during the execution phase
    println paramA
    println paramB
}

task taskC() << {
    //properties are printed during the execution phase
    println paramA
    println paramB
}

task taskB(){
    def val1 = '1'
    def val2 = 'abc'

    //here you set task properties
    taskA.ext.paramA=val1
    taskA.ext.paramB=val2

    //here you set task properties
    taskC.ext.paramA=val1
    taskC.ext.paramB=val2

    //provide task depoendencies
    dependsOn taskA, taskC
    //and tasks order
    taskC.mustRunAfter taskA
}
```

In that case `ext` means, that this property is not a global, but owned only by task itself.

The problem with the example above is the fact, that the values propagated by `taskB` are available in `taskA` and `taskC` only at the execution phase. If you need them during configuration, you can pass them as project properties, like:

```
task taskB(){
    def val1 = '1'
    def val2 = 'abc'

    //here you set project properties
    project.ext.paramA=val1
    project.ext.paramB=val2
}

task taskA() {
    //properties are printed during the configuration phase
    println project.ext.paramA
    println project.ext.paramB
}

task taskC() << {
    //properties are printed during the execution phase
    println project.ext.paramA
    println project.ext.paramB
}

//provide task depoendencies
taskB.dependsOn taskA, taskC
//and tasks order
taskC.mustRunAfter taskA
```

Comment: I'm getting an error - Error:(32, 0) Could not find property 'taskA' on task ':taskB'.

Comment: @user990635 is the task order the same? I mean, `taskA` and `taskC` have to be declared before `taskB`

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the order. Now I'm getting another error: Error:(62, 0) Could not find property 'paramA' on task ':taskA'. I've also tried to use something like: if (project.hasProperty("paramA")), but the result is false

Comment: @user990635 it's not a project property, but of the task itself. I suppose, you are trying to use it at the configuration phase. Note `<<` which is equals to `doLast` and execute tho closure at rhe execution, bot configuration

Comment: @user990635 added one more example to the answer. Here you can pass variables into the task during the configuration phase too. But note, that task order is changed.

Comment: Thanks! the second solution helped! when I added "<<" to the first solution it caused another problem because my taskB dependsOn taskD, taskE, so it was failing.